# Magento2 Which table store category ascending order or descending order store category

Tags: magento2, category, menu, topmenu, sub-categories

My project category and sub category I have set ascending order or descending order store category via script or sql query.

Magento2 Which table store category & sub category ascending order or descending order store category.

Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: I'm sorry but this question is really hard to understand. Can you try to rephrase it or make it clearer?

Comment: The sort order for categories by default is position which is in the catalog_category_entity table the order of them is defined when the collection is called.

Comment: Thank you for Dava Gorden but I have set ascending order or descending order store category via script or sql query.